# Can't Access JSON Properties Of Firestore Data With String Interpolation

Tags: json, angular, firebase, string-interpolation, google-cloud-firestore

I can't access the properties of my Firestore document during string Interpolation. The regular JSON output works fine though. Here's the code:

### **Working**

```
<h3>{{ teacher | async | json }}</h3>
```

**Output:**

[image: Output - Working]

---

### **Not working**

```
<h3>{{ teacher.name | async | json }}</h3>
```

and

```
<h3>{{ teacher.name | async }}</h3>
```

**Output:**

[image: Output - Not Working]

---

**Typescript code**

```
interface Teacher {
  name: string;
}

teacherDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Teacher>;
teacher: Observable<Teacher>;

var placeToSearch = 'Teachers/'+this.selectedTeacher;

this.teacherDoc = this.afs.doc(placeToSearch);
this.teacher = this.teacherDoc.valueChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just slightly off with the async pipe. The object needs to be unwrapped first, then you call it's properties. It should look like:

```
{{ (teacher | async)?.name }}
```

Or better yet, set a template variable to avoid using the async pipe over and over:

```
<div *ngIf="teacher | async as t">
  {{ t.name }}
  {{ t.field }}
  {{ t.whatever }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your interface should have both name and field

```
interface Teacher {
  name: string;
  field: string;
}

<h3>{{ teacher?.name | async  }}</h3>
```

Comment: I added the field property and changed the <h3> tag in the template to how you did it, but now the h3 doesn't show up at all.

Comment: @FiringBlanks strange!